# How to get product level data point form google analytics using api?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Hi I was trying to get the E-commerce related data points like (totalProductDetailViews , totalAddedToCart, totalProductCheckout and cartConversions) from google analytics using google analytics api. But I was unable find a way how to do it?

Google gave direct metrics for all the data points described above, but that is at account level not product level. How can I get products page level data?

Comment: Can you please show what have you done so far?

Comment: ```function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
 $optParams = array( 'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=@/my/url' ); 
return $analytics->data_ga->get( 'ga:' . $profileId, '7daysAgo', 'today', 'ga:pageViews,ga:productDetailViews,ga:productAddsToCart,ga:transactionsPerSession', $optParams );
 }``` 
I am not getting the correct data and also getting the number of results varying for different time intervals?